# Hot observable consume with different frequency

Tags: scala, concurrency, observable, monix

I am working on a simple example for the task I am trying to complete.
Let's say there is a list of tasks (`tasks`) that I want to **trigger every 1 second**.

That could be done with a `scheduler` or whatever.

Now there are two consumers of this stream, **but**

- `C1` should trigger on completion of all tasks
- `C2` should trigger on every n-th completion of all tasks. (Can be also every n seconds)

Here is some sample code. Currently, it is not scheduled to repeat - because I do not know if it is better to use `Observable.repeat` or a `Scheduler`.

```
import monix.eval.Task
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global
import monix.execution.Scheduler.{global => scheduler}
import monix.reactive.{Consumer, Observable}

import scala.concurrent.duration._

object MainTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    def t = (i: Int) => Observable.eval {
      print(i)
      i
    }

    val tsks = (1 to 5).map(t)

    val tasks = Observable.fromIterable(tsks).flatten.doOnCompleteEval(Task.eval(println("")))

    val c1 = Consumer.foreach[Int](x => println(s"C1: [$x]"))
    val c2 = Consumer.foreach[Int](x => println(s"C2: [$x]"))

    val s = tasks.reduce(_ + _).publish

    s.consumeWith(c1).runAsync
    s.consumeWith(c2).runAsync
    s.connect()

    while (true) {
      Thread.sleep(1.hour.toMillis)
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for repeating a task every 1 second, you can do ...

```
Observable.intervalAtFixedRate(1.second)
  .flatMap(_ => Observable.eval(???))
```

For triggering on completion of all tasks, you can use either `completed` (if you want an `Observable[Nothing]` which emits only the final completion event) or `completedL` (if you want to work with a `Task[Unit]` instead).
See the [API docs](https://monix.io/api/2.3/monix/reactive/Observable.html#completed:Self[Nothing]) for details.

So instead of your `c1` thing, you can do:

```
s.completeL.runAsync
```

For sampling the source however, you can work with:

- `sample` (alias `throttleLast`)
- `sampleRepeated`
- `throttleFirst`
- `debounce`
- `debounceRepeated`
- `echo`
- `echoRepeated`

I encourage you to play with these, start with the [API docs](https://monix.io/api/2.3/monix/reactive/Observable.html).

```
s.sample(10.seconds).doOnNext(println).completedL.runAsync
```

Or you can simply take every Nth elements with `takeEveryNth`:

```
s.takeEveryNth(20).doOnNext(println).completedL.runAsync
```

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: I think I now can see clearly my difficulty. If I `flatMap` my `source` with observable emitted every 1 second, this stream is no longer finite. So I completely lost my "cycle" information, which is important to me. If I `map` instead of `flatMap` i keep it, but i get `Observable[Observable[Int]]`.
And then its more difficult to manage the flow.

Comment: Above comment helped me to understand the case. My cycle should be an item of this Observable.. and Bob's my uncle.